# Any Windows bootable media won't boot after fixing GRUB2

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, grub, efi

Recently, I accidentally deleted EFI and Windows partition. Then, I tried fixing the GRUB first on a Ubuntu bootable media (it booted fine). After that, I made Windows bootable using Rufus. But, the Windows bootable won't boot even after I put it on the highest boot order, choosing from boot menu didn't help either.

Any ideas or solutions for that?

Comment: Why did you delete the EFI?

Comment: I deleted Windows and EFI partition beacuse of BitLocker accidentally turned on (at that time i thought that those 2 drives was the problem so i deleted it)

Comment: Try not to relate the two things that just aren't related. Have you thought that maybe you did something wrong when prepare the drive?

Comment: Nope, I guess..